# Django query Many to Many fields and get queryset based on each filter

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I have the following problem to filter my group table with its realizations so that I only get the data set that matches the filter settings.

My models look like this:

Group:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    products = models.ManyToManyField('Product')
    subgroups = models.ManyToManyField('Subgroup')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Subgroup:

```
class Subgroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    products = models.ManyToManyField('Product')
    order = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    is_hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Product:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    is_hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Currently, my query returns all groups that match at least one of the filters, but I want to apply the filter per model.

```
non_hidden_groups = Group.objects.filter(user=user, is_hidden=False).filter(subgroups__is_hidden=False).filter(products__is_hidden=False)
```

The problem is that I get a queryset back that exclude groups that are not hidden, but for example contains subgroups that are hidden. 
I only want to exclude:

- all groups that are marked as `is_hidden`
- all subgroups in the group that are marked as `is_hidden`
- all products in the group that are marked as `is_hidden`
- all products in a subgroup in a group that are marked as `is_hidden`

This is how the query looks like:

```
class Query(ObjectType):
    groups = List(GroupType, exclude_hidden_groups=Boolean(required=False),
                          exclude_hidden_subgroups=Boolean(required=False),
                          exclude_hidden_products=Boolean(required=False))

def resolve_groups(self, info, exclude_hidden_groups=False, exclude_hidden_subgroups=False, exclude_hidden_products=False, **kwargs):
    user = info.context.user
    groups = Group.objects.filter(user=user,is_hidden=exclude_hidden_groups).filter(subgroups__is_hidden=exclude_hidden_subgroups).filter(products__is_hidden=exclude_hidden_products)
    # problem here is that a group is also excluded if it contains a subgroup/product that is marked as hidden
    return groups
```

Has anyone an idea how to do this without converting the queries into a list?

Comment: You have to filter the subgroups and products separately, I assume you are looping through the groups then have nested loops for the subgroups and products?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but how can I then make one queryset with all the nested ones?

Comment: You won’t be able to do it with one queryset as you need to filter each relation on the instances, if you provide your view/template I may be able to help a bit better

Comment: The thing is that django is used with `graphene`, so this is a `GraphQL` query. But I think it doesn't matter what happens in this query or how it is used, more important is to solve this general problem of relations from many to many fields?! But if necessary I could provide the query too.

Comment: Well it would be better to provide this sort of info when you ask the question as the models and queryset you have provided are standard Django, for any further help please provide how you are accessing the subgroups/products